# Media query and symfony encore

Tags: css, symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm currently working on my portfolio and more specifically on the front-end. My project use Symfony so I'm using Symfony Encore to manage my front-end assets.

When I work on a project I split my CSS into different files, one by media query, so a mobile user doesn't have to load the CSS for desktops.

```
<link rel="stylesheets" href="/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheets" href="/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)">
```

When you use Symfony Encore, you must specify an entry inside the webpack.config.js using `addStyleEntry` or `addEntry`. To include your compiled asset inside your vues you need to use `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('style') }}`.

The problem is that I would like to specify the media attribute of my `<link>` and I don't know how to do that. I have also tried to use `{{ asset("style.css") }}` but it did not worked.

Comment: you can use `{{ asset() }}` but give the complete path relative from `/public` where encore where encore placed the files

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the encore dev-server and I thought that wouldn't be working with hmr this way but it works.